# What is the definition of "mod p lower central series"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I am wondering what is the exact definition of "mod $p$ lower central series"?

Is it the same thing as the "lower p-central series" as presented here: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81193793.pdf?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give a reference where you saw this term? I would expect it means you also kill p-torsion in the series factors, but that might not be exactly right.

Comment: I find this term here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938366900243

Comment: That paper references the paper you linked, so I'm guessing they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same, in that article they use what is called the Zassenhauss filtration.
The definition of the lower p-central series (also known as Stallings filtration ) of a group G is given recursively by the rule:
$G_1=G, \;
G_{i+1}= [G,G_i](G_i)^p.$